# How do I arrange files in a folder in some particuar order?

Tags: dual-boot, files, directory

I have saved a set of drivers required for Windows in one of my hard-disk partitions. Now I want to arrange them in some particular order such as

1. BIOS
2. Drivers
3. Applications

I want the order of these drivers to be reflected even when I access them in Windows.

Because this is the order in which I should install the drivers for my Windows to work properly.

When I boot into Windows, I would be installing the drivers in the same order.
How can I do it in Ubuntu ?

Is there any way besides changing all the file names such that they are in an alphabetic order corresponding to the order in which they should be installed ?

Comment: You could modify the "modified" and "created" timestamps, and then sort them by date - but alphabetically would be easier I think - just prefix them with incrementing numbers. you could also put them into different folders.